What did I do wrong? SQL
I'm trying to generate a report that shows the number of times each student attended exams for each subject, including students and subjects with zero attendances. I have three tables: Students, Subjects, and Examinations.
Input:
Students table:
+------------+--------------+
| student_id | student_name |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | Alice        |
| 2          | Bob          |
| 13         | John         |
| 6          | Alex         |
+------------+--------------+

Subjects table:
+--------------+
| subject_name |
+--------------+
| Math         |
| Physics      |
| Programming  |
+--------------+

Examinations table:
+------------+--------------+
| student_id | subject_name |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | Math         |
| 1          | Physics      |
| 1          | Programming  |
| 2          | Programming  |
| 1          | Physics      |
| 1          | Math         |
| 13         | Math         |
| 13         | Programming  |
| 13         | Physics      |
| 2          | Math         |
| 1          | Math         |
+------------+--------------+

Output:
+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+
| student_id | student_name | subject_name | attended_exams |
+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+
| 1          | Alice        | Math         | 3              |
| 1          | Alice        | Physics      | 2              |
| 1          | Alice        | Programming  | 1              |
| 2          | Bob          | Math         | 1              |
| 2          | Bob          | Physics      | 0              |
| 2          | Bob          | Programming  | 1              |
| 6          | Alex         | Math         | 0              |
| 6          | Alex         | Physics      | 0              |
| 6          | Alex         | Programming  | 0              |
| 13         | John         | Math         | 1              |
| 13         | John         | Physics      | 1              |
| 13         | John         | Programming  | 1              |
+------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+

Explanation:
The result table should contain all students and all subjects.
Alice attended the Math exam 3 times, the Physics exam 2 times, and the Programming exam 1 time.
Bob attended the Math exam 1 time, the Programming exam 1 time, and did not attend the Physics exam.
Alex did not attend any exams.
John attended the Math exam 1 time, the Physics exam 1 time, and the Programming exam 1 time.
Here is my code:
SELECT s1.student_id, s1.student_name, e.subject_name, COUNT(e.subject_name) AS attended_exams
FROM Students s1
JOIN Examinations e ON e.student_id = s1.student_id
LEFT JOIN Subjects s2 ON s2.subject_name = e.subject_name
GROUP BY s1.student_id, s1.student_name, e.subject_name
ORDER BY s1.student_id ASC, s1.student_name ASC

And it is my output:
+------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
| student_id | student_name | subject_name  | attended_exams |
+------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
|          1 | Alice        | Math          |              3 |
|          1 | Alice        | Physics       |              2 |
|          1 | Alice        | Programming   |              1 |
|          2 | Bob          | Math          |              1 |
|          2 | Bob          | Programming   |              1 |
|         13 | John         | Math          |              1 |
|         13 | John         | Physics       |              1 |
|         13 | John         | Programming   |              1 |
+------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+

I double-checked with the solution, but found none of the difference. Could someone help me fix my code to get the expected output?

Why have you tagged with [tag:syntax-error]? What syntax errors are you encountering? Judging by your question, it doesn't seem like this is actually relevant. If so, can you remove this tag and instead replace it with the tag for the DBMS you're using?

Assuming your DBMS supports it, have you tried using an CROSS JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN for Subjects? Seems that's closer to what you're after; if you need a listing of all students and subjects even if attended_exams = 0, it's not clear why you'd select the latter over the former.

@esqew I think RIGHT JOIN is enough. You do not need a subject that nobody took.

@PM77-1 Curious, how'd you reach the conclusion that the OP does "not need a subject that nobody took"? They didn't mention a requirement one way or the other, unless I've missed something.

@esqew - I inferred from the way the desired result is presented.

use a cross join instead of a left join
SELECT s.student_id, s.student_name, sub.subject_name,
       COALESCE(COUNT(e.student_id), 0) AS attended_exams
FROM Students s
CROSS JOIN Subjects sub
LEFT JOIN Examinations e ON e.student_id = s.student_id
                         AND e.subject_name = sub.subject_name
GROUP BY s.student_id, s.student_name, sub.subject_name
ORDER BY s.student_id ASC, sub.subject_name ASC;

